# To check if input is in range(x,y)

Tags: python, python-3.8

I check if user input is in range 1-5 if the answer is not in range 1-5 number should entered again till is between 1-5.
I tried many ways, Googled, checked other answers on stack but whatever I try it's not doing what I do want.
Here are my approaches:

```
choice = input('Your number: ')

while choice not in range(1,6):
    choice = input('Your number again: ')
else:
    print('ok')

#output:
Your number: 2
Your number again: 3
Your number again: 4
Your number again: 5
Your number again: 6
Your number again: 7
Your number again: 8
Your number again: 9
Your number again: 

--------------------------------------
#another go

choice = input('Your number: ')

while choice != (x for x in range(1,6)):
    choice = input('Your number again: ')
else:
    print('ok')
#output:
Your number: 2
Your number again: 4
Your number again: 8
Your number again: 

--------------------------------------
#Another go


choice = input('Enter the number ')

if choice == range(1,6):
    print('Good')
else:
    print('nope, must be in range 1 - 5')

#output
Enter the number 3
nope, must be in range 1 - 5
```

Comment: `input` returns a string; try `int(input(...))` instead. You will need some separate logic to handle if they don't enter a number at all.

Comment: It's a good tip and solving problem.
Thanks